# How to forward only specific requests with node-http-proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, node-http-proxy

I want to use `node-http-proxy` to forward requests only with certain content-type header. Since i want to filter requests, i can't just use `forward` option of proxy server.
My idea is to use `proxyReq` event and if request satisfies conditions, forward it to another server. Can you give me example how can i do this?

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),

    proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    if (req.headers['content-type']==='text/xml') {
        // send it to target and also forward to another server
    }
});


var app = connect()
    .use(function (req, res) {
        proxy.web(req, res,
            {
                target: {
                    port: 8081,
                    host: 'localhost'
                }
            })
    });

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('proxy listen 8080');
});
```